# Dynamically Load python Module

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I created a server where users can return a table as JSON representation.

What I wanted to do have the user create a python module that inherits from a Reader Base.  This isn't the issue.  The issue is how do I make it do my server can dynamically load each library to read each file type?

I hope I explained this well.  If not please ask questions.

Thank you,
J

I do not believe this is a duplicate because the python modules may or may not exists and will be added to the system on run time.

Comment: So, you want to save an arbitrary number of objects that you import from modules? How will your program get signalled that there is a new module to load?

Comment: The proposed duplicate specifically talks about "find the available command modules at runtime" so it still seems to be the same question to me.